# How to add quantization noise (SQNR) to thermal noise (SNR) in a total value?

Tags: noise, snr, quantization

How can I add the BAQ (Block Adaptive Quantizer) compression noise to the input SNR? In the end is a quantization noise to be added to a thermal noise. I got the following formulation, but I dont understand the second one. I would have expected the total snr to be 1/(1/snr + 1/sqnr) instead. Can someone explain? thanks!

sqnr = 10.^((6.09*Nbit-2.03)/10); % quantization noise

snr_tot = 1./(1./snr.*(1+1./sqnr)+1./sqnr) % total noise

Comment: _Where_ did you get that formulation.  If you're working off of some reference, cite it, and maybe quote some of the surrounding description.

Comment: Sorry I don't have it. It comes from a friend